# array is undefined in component being rendered with enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I've got a simple component that uses the useSelector and useDispatch hooks to dispatch and get the current state from my redux store and map over them to return a child component.

I'm new to testing with hooks and after following some articles, I mocked the two redux hooks with jest mock to see if they are called when mounted, however, when running the test my state array is returned as undefined so the test fails. Does anyone know why this is happening?

COMPONENT.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { getData } from '../actions/index';
import { AppState } from '../store/store';

import GridItem from '../component/GridItem';

function GridContainer () {        
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const books = useSelector((state: AppState) => state);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getData());
    }, [dispatch]);
   
    const bookList = (list: AppState) => {
        return list.map((book) => (
            <GridItem key={book.id} data={ book } />
        ))
    };

    return (
        <div className="book-container">
            { bookList(books) }
        </div>
    )
}

export default GridContainer;
```

COMPONENT.test.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';

import GridContainer from './GridContainer';

const mockDispatch = jest.fn();

jest.mock("react-redux", () => ({
    useSelector: jest.fn(fn => fn()),
    useDispatch: () => mockDispatch
}));

it('renders container', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<GridContainer />);
    const component = wrapper.find('.book-container');

    expect(component.length).toBe(1);
});

describe('react hooks', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    it('runs dispatch on mount', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(<GridContainer />);

        expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

ERROR msg

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

      25 |     //function to print list of books component
      26 |     const bookList = (list: AppState) => {
    > 27 |         return list.map((book) => (
         |                     ^
      28 |             <GridItem key={book.id} data={ book } />
      29 |         ))
      30 |     };
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with mocking `useSelector`. the function itself pass `AppState` to a callback, but a mock function is not aware of `AppState`. In this way your mock will return undefined. In this way `books` (list) will be `undefined`.

you need to specify what your mock will return, in this case an array. you can call `mockReturnValue` passing a booksMock (an array) for that:

```
jest.mock("react-redux", () => ({
    useSelector: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(booksMock),
    useDispatch: () => mockDispatch
}));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back, I tried your solution however the error is the same, after looking at it a bit more, it seems enzyme is not picking up my redux state for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You should mock the return value of `useSelector` hook.

E.g.

`GridContainer.tsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { getData } from './actions/index';
import { AppState } from './store/store';
import GridItem from './component/GridItem';

function GridContainer() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const books = useSelector((state: AppState) => state);
  console.log('books:', books);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getData());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const bookList = (list: AppState) => {
    return list.map((book) => <GridItem key={book.id} data={book} />);
  };

  return <div className="book-container">{bookList(books)}</div>;
}

export default GridContainer;
```

`./component/GridItem.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function GridItem({ data }) {
  return <div>{data.name}</div>;
}
```

`./store/store.ts`:

```
export type AppState = any[];
```

`./actions/index.ts`:

```
export function getData() {
  return { type: 'GET_DATA' };
}
```

`GridContainer.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import GridContainer from './GridContainer';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const mockDispatch = jest.fn();
const booksMock = [
  { id: 1, name: 'golang' },
  { id: 2, name: 'TypeScript' },
];

jest.mock('react-redux', () => {
  return {
    useSelector: jest.fn(() => booksMock),
    useDispatch: jest.fn(() => mockDispatch),
  };
});

describe('react hooks', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('renders container', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<GridContainer />);
    const component = wrapper.find('.book-container');
    expect(component.length).toBe(1);
  });

  it('runs dispatch on mount', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<GridContainer />);
    expect(useDispatch).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(useSelector).toBeCalledWith(expect.any(Function));
    expect(mockDispatch).toBeCalledWith({ type: 'GET_DATA' });
    expect(wrapper.find('.book-container').children()).toHaveLength(2);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65172098/GridContainer.test.tsx
  react hooks
    ✓ renders container (65 ms)
    ✓ runs dispatch on mount (44 ms)

  console.log
    books: [ { id: 1, name: 'golang' }, { id: 2, name: 'TypeScript' } ]

      at GridContainer (examples/65172098/GridContainer.tsx:11:11)

  console.log
    books: [ { id: 1, name: 'golang' }, { id: 2, name: 'TypeScript' } ]

      at GridContainer (examples/65172098/GridContainer.tsx:11:11)

--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files           |      95 |      100 |   85.71 |     100 |                   
 65172098           |   93.33 |      100 |      80 |     100 |                   
  GridContainer.tsx |   93.33 |      100 |      80 |     100 |                   
 65172098/actions   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  index.ts          |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 65172098/component |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  GridItem.tsx      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.442 s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/tree/main/examples/65172098